# Removing spacing between datawindow bands

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I am having an issue with spacing between the summary and footer band. Note, only detail and footer bands are used. Is there a way to remove the spacing between summary and footer band?
i.e i want the footer to be right under the information in details tab. There seems to be a 20 pix difference.

Tabular datawindow is being used.

```
Header (height =0)
Detail (height = 800 + autoheight  enabled )
Summary (height = 0)
Footer (height = 250)
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You cannot completely remove the summary band. its default horizontal band in Powerbuilder.

Regards 
 
Raj